# CRA variable replacement in public index.html

Tags: reactjs, deployment, create-react-app

I understand the purpose of `%PUBLIC_URL%`, however I also understand and have observed that you cannot set `PUBLIC_URL` and have it replaced during a development (local) run. I have run into the following situation.

I have to reference a script resource which is hosted on a server specific to the deployment environment. I need to grab this resource from a different host, depending on whether this is a development run or is deployed (e.g. QA):

1. if running locally, then the script needs to come from "https://my-dev-server" (that is, when running locally, the script should be pulled from the DEV environment)
2. if deployed to DEV, QA, or PROD, then the script needs to come from `%PUBLIC_URL%`

This already works for deployed environments (#2 above) if I use a script tag such as ...

```html
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/a/b/c/my-script.js></script>
```

However, when running locally, `%PUBLIC_URL%` is replaced with "" (empty string), so my script is fetched from "/a/b/c/my-script.js" which results in a 404.

How can I have a custom environment variable replaced, e.g. "DEPLOY_HOST", and a script tag like ...

```html
<script src="https://%DEPLOY_HOST%/a/b/c/my-script.js></script>
```

Note: using react-scripts v2.1.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Create two .env file in your root directory*

```
// file name: .env.development
REACT_APP_MY_API=https://dev.api
```

```
// file name: .env.production
REACT_APP_MY_API=https://production.api
```

**Please note**: In order for this to work the variable names must start with `REACT_APP_` otherwise it won't work.

In your index.html, you can do this now:

```html
<script>
  console.log('%REACT_APP_MY_API%'); // This will change based on development or production
</script>
```

Or you can:

```html
<script src="%REACT_APP_MY_API%/a/b/c/my-script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there might be a less clunky way e.g. simply variable replacement, but I'll have to go with something like this.

Comment: @JoshM.I've include another approach, which is a simply variable replacement, it's also a CRA built-in feature.

Comment: I tried the variable replacement, just as you have it, but it did not work -- does it require a specific version of react-scripts?

Comment: @JoshM.My bad, I've update whole new answer for you.

Comment: it could have perhaps been that the vaiables must begin with `REACT_APP_` otherwise it won't work, I have updated the answer to reflect this